# Footnotes with automatic final period not working with package acro

Tags: footnotes, acronyms, acro

I have a little problem with my footnotes. I'm using a solution to add a period at the end of every `\footnote{}` (yes, I have to use `\footnote{}` and not `\footcite{}` because I have to add some text in my footnotes, too) and most of the time it works fine. But when I'm using an acronym (`\ac{}`) that is at the at of a sentence in a footnote it doesn't work. I'm pretty sure it's because of the `\acdot` which provides that at the end of a sentence (in the main text) won't be two dots. But I have no clue how to solve this problem. Hopefully, someone could help me.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[german=guillemets]{csquotes}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[style=german-legal-book]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{mylit.bib}

\bibliography{mylit}
\begin{filecontents}{mylit.bib}
@article{Smith,
Author={Smith, John},
Journal={ExamplePaper},
Title={Titel},
Year={2006},
Number={5},
Pages={1--10}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{acro}
\acsetup{
  list/template  = styleabbrev,
  list/heading   = chapter,
  list/name      = Abkürzungsverzeichnis
}

\DeclareAcronym{mwN}{
short = m.~w.~N\acdot ,
long = mit weiterem Nachweis ,
first-style = short
}


\let\orgfootnote\footnote
\newcommand\myautodot{%
\ifthenelse{\the\spacefactor>\sfcode`,}{}{.}%
}
\renewcommand\footnote[2][\empty]{%
\ifx#1\empty%
\orgfootnote{\normalsfcodes#2\myautodot}%
\else%
\orgfootnote[#1]{\normalsfcodes#2\myautodot}%
\fi%
}

\begin{document}

There are no two dots at the end of sentence \ac{mwN}.\footnote{And here in the footnote is a dot at the end of the sentence}

Some text.\footnote{No two dots at the end of the sentence.}

Some more text.\footnote{Some text \cite[2]{Smith}}

Different text.\footnote{I like \cite[4]{Smith}.}

Here is a dot.\footnote{But here, I only want one dot not two \ac{mwN}}


\end{document}
```

Comment: `\footnote{But here, I only want one dot not two \ac{mwN}\spacefactor1001 }`

Comment: I don't know why but it doesn't work for me... I still get two dots at the end of the sentence in the footnote...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`acro`](https://ctan.org/pkg/acro) is configured to look for a literal `.` and absorb that if present, we have a similar problem to yours using just

```
\newcommand\mydot{.}
\ac{mwN}\mydot
```

in the main text.

In order to have `\myautodot` be absorbed [`acro`](https://ctan.org/pkg/acro) needs to be told that it is a trailing character that `\acdot`-type macros may wish to absorb, and should be allowed to with the `register` (documented erroneously as `define`) and `activate` keys.  Assuming we always want `\acdot` to absorb both `.` and `\myautodot` we can redefine it so it looks for `dot` (the internal name [`acro`](https://ctan.org/pkg/acro) uses for `.`) and `autodot` (which is what we've named `\myautodot`)

```
\acsetup{
trailing/register = \myautodot {autodot},
trailing/activate = {autodot}
}
\renewcommand*\acdot{\aciftrailing{dot,autodot}{}{\abbrdot}}
```

Comment: It works perfectly! Thank you very much!