# Footnotes with automatic final period not working with glossaries-extra

Tags: footnotes, acronyms, glossaries-extra

I have a little problem with my footnotes and using package glossaries-extra. I'm using a solution ([see here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/594567/229073)) to add a period at the end of every `\footnote{}` (yes, I have to use `\footnote{}` and not `\footcite{}` because I have to add some text in my footnotes, too) and most of the time it works fine. But when I'm using an abbreviation (`\gls{}`) which ends with a period at the end of a sentence in a footnote it doesn't work. I'll get two periods. I have no clue how to solve this problem. Hopefully, someone could help me. (I had a similiar question but with package acro [[see here]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/642437/footnotes-with-automatic-final-period-not-working-with-package-acro).)

MWE:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,fontsize=12pt]{scrbook}
\KOMAoptions{twoside=false}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[german=guillemets]{csquotes}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[style=german-legal-book]{biblatex}
\setmainfont{ebgaramond}[]
\usepackage[style=long,nogroupskip,nonumberlist]{glossaries-extra}
\setabbreviationstyle{short-nolong}
\glssetcategoryattribute{abbreviation}{noshortplural}{true}
\glssetcategoryattribute{abbreviationdot}{discardperiod}{true}
%
\newabbreviation[%
     description={mit weiteren/m Nachweisen/Nachweis},%Darstellung der longform im Abkürzungsverzeichnis
     category=abbreviationdot,%
     longplural={mit weiteren Nachweisen},%
     shortplural=m.~w.~N.,
     sort={mwN},%
     ]%
     {mwN}%key
     {m.~w.~N.}%shortform
     {mit weiterem Nachweis}%longform
%
%automatic final period in footnote
\makeatletter%
\long\def\@makefntext#1{%
   \parindent 1em\noindent \hb@xt@ 1.8em{\hss\@makefnmark}#1%
   \ifnum\the\spacefactor<3000
     \ifnum\the\spacefactor=\blx@sf@period
     \else
     .%
     \fi
   \fi}
\makeatother
%
\begin{document}
There are no two dots at the end of sentence \gls{mwN}.\footnote{And here in the footnote is a dot at the end of the sentence}
Here is a dot.\footnote{But here, I only want one dot not two: \gls{mwN}}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution which seems to work. It's based on this [issue](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/1071).

MWE:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,fontsize=12pt] {scrbook}
\KOMAoptions{twoside=false}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[german=guillemets]{csquotes}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[style=german-legal-book]{biblatex}
\setmainfont{ebgaramond}[]
\usepackage[style=long,nogroupskip,nonumberlist]{glossaries-extra}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\setabbreviationstyle{short-nolong}
\glssetcategoryattribute{abbreviation}{noshortplural}{true}
\glssetcategoryattribute{abbreviationdot}{discardperiod}{true}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\addperiod}{\blx@imc@addperiod}  
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\protected\def\blx@imc@addperiod{%
  \ifnum\blx@spacefactor=999
    \@%
  \fi
  \blx@addpunct{period}%
  \ifnum\blx@spacefactor=\blx@sf@dot
    \spacefactor\blx@sf@period
  \fi}

\makeatother
%automatic final period in footnote
\makeatletter%
\long\def\@makefntext#1{%
  \parindent 2em%
  \hangindent = 1.7em%
  \hangafter = 1%
  \noindent %
  \hb@xt@ 1.6em{\hss\@makefnmark\hspace{0,1 cm}}#1%\parindent 1em\noindent \hb@xt@ 1.8em{\hss\@makefnmark}#1        \makebox[0.5em][l]
  \ifnum\the\spacefactor<3000
    \ifnum\the\spacefactor=\blx@sf@period
    \else
    .%
    \fi
  \fi}
\makeatother

\newabbreviation[%
    description={mit weiteren/m Nachweisen/Nachweis},%Darstellung der longform im Abkürzungsverzeichnis
    category=abbreviationdot,%
    longplural={mit weiteren Nachweisen},%
    shortplural=m.~w.~N\addperiod,
    sort={mwN},%
    ]%
    {mwN}%key
    {m.~w.~N\addperiod}%shortform
    {mit weiterem Nachweis}%longform
%
\begin{document}

There are no two dots at the end of sentence \gls{mwN}.\footnote{And here in the footnote is a dot at the end of the sentence}

Here is a dot.\footnote{But here, I only want one dot not two: \gls{mwN}}

\end{document}
```